# SUM of sales , group by month, org unit and product

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this

```
select * from promet_3b;
```

Colum DATUM is date; ORGJED is organisational unit, RGRUPA is our product type and KOLICINA is quantity.

I would like to have table like this.

1)  Column MONTH (jan-feb-...)

2) COLUMN ORGJED

3) COLUMN RGRUPA

4) COLUMN KOL1- sum of quantity till start of month

5) COLUMN KOL2 - sum of quantity till end of month

For example in APRIL is KOL2=300, that is the KOL1 in MAY

Comment: What have you tried? Also, please do not post table data as images - post it as formatted text or, even better, as DDL & DML statements. Similarly for your expected output - please post your expected output as formatted text as the current format is unclear. See [MCVE].

Comment: Thans for advice. I am new here ,so dont know all things.

Comment: So.... You don't care about the year?  Feb 2015 and Feb 2016 would both be grouped into the sum in Kol1?

Comment: I have tried next query :
select orgjed,extract (month from datum) as Month,rgrupa, sum (kolicina) as SUM from mlp1
where datum <'01-FEB-2016' and orgjed=:p1 and rgrupa=:p2
group by orgjed, extract (month from datum),rgrupa
order by orgjed,extract (month from datum),rgrupa;

Comment: @xQbert It does care ofcourse. Thanks for reminding me for that. This is only for 2016 year. But when i figured it up for 2016, i hope that the rest can do?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query will give you desired result...Please check...

```
SELECT ORGJED,RGRUPA, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM S.DATUM) CUR_MONTH,
         EXTRACT (YEAR FROM S.DATUM) CUR_YEAR,
         SUM (S.KOLICINA) KOLICINA,
         NVL (
            LAG (
               SUM (S.KOLICINA))
            OVER (PARTITION by ORGJED,RGRUPA
               ORDER BY ORGJED,RGRUPA,
                  EXTRACT (YEAR FROM S.DATUM),
                  EXTRACT (MONTH FROM S.DATUM)),
            0)
            PREV_MONTH
    FROM mlp1 s
GROUP BY ORGJED,RGRUPA,
         EXTRACT (MONTH FROM S.DATUM),
         EXTRACT (YEAR FROM S.DATUM)
```